# Linkage failure when building qt class with Makefile

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

I'm trying added such class to a project^

```
//Emitter.h
#ifndef EMITTER_H
#define EMITTER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDBusInterface>
#include <QDBusAbstractAdaptor>
#include <QDBusVariant>

class Emitter:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Emitter();

private:
    QDBusInterface * m_interface;
    QString m_interfaceName;
};

#endif // EMITTER_H
```

and

```
//Emitter.cpp 
#include "CESMEmitter.moc"
#include "Emitter.h"
Emitter::Emitter( QObject * parent )
     : QObject( parent )
{
}
```

CESMEmitter.moc file I received by using moc like this:

```
moc CESMEmitter.h > CESMEmitter.moc
```

After trying to build with Makefile I received an error, sayng that Qt include files were not found.

So I added variable

```
QT_STUFF = -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtDBus -I/usr/include/qt4 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQtGui -lQtCore -lQtDBus -lpthread
```

And applied it.

The include files were found, but other errors arised:

```
error: undefined reference to `QObject::QObject(QObject*)'
error: undefined reference to `qt_assert(char const*, char const*, int)'
error: undefined reference to `QString::shared_null'
error: undefined reference to `QString::shared_null'
```

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: add the qt lib folder to LIBS: `LIBS+="-l/path/to/qt/lib"`

Comment: I have it added, it's -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu in QT_STUFF

Comment: does that also get passed to the linker?

Comment: Yes as the whole QT_STUFF is passed

Comment: kopalvich: why not use LIBS? Also, you should not use "moc CESMEmitter.h > CESMEmitter.moc", but you could use the output option of moc...

Answer (score 0):

Although it may happen to work, you shouldn't just have one `QT_STUFF` variable. You need a separate one for the compilation (with `-I` and `-D`) and linking (with `-L/-l`). You're also likely missing the necessary defines for the compilation. Qt 4 needs

```
-DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED
```

and similar for all of the Qt libraries that you use. Qt 5 needs

```
-DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB
```

Are you also sure that the linker doesn't complain about missing Qt libraries?

It might be easier to at least let qmake generate the initial Makefile that you can then tweak.